# Partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, pandas, import

Trying to run the following in python (Keeping it simple) but get a strange error.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
```

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I've already tried:

1. deleting pandas and reinstalling it
2. Looked for files named pandas.py in my folder
3. renaming files

Answer (score 1):

Your Python file can't be called the same name as a Python *module* that you're importing. Rename your `pandas.py` file to something else, like `pandas_work.py`.